# Navigating to child node in angular (like Windows Explorer)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object with this structure

```
{
   Name: 'A',
   CreatedOn: new Date(),
   Directories: [
      {
         Name: 'A.1',
         CreatedOn: new Date(),
         Directories: []
      },
      {
        Name: 'A.2',
        CreatedOn: new Date(),
        Directories: [
          {
             Name: 'A.2.1',
             CreatedOn: new Date(),
             Directories: []
          }
        ]
      }
   ]
}
```

and i want to create a directive to navigate from "A" to "A.1" then manipulate "A.1" *like change date* then navigate to "A.2".. So basically, my idea is to pass the object itself if to where is the current directive is pointing. like i have a method that says NavigateTo(scope, currentValue) where **currentValue** is the node in the hierarchy. another idea is to recreate the directive and pass the node to it then the previous node will be stored in some array.

My problem now is since my dom has binding **ng-model** the Variable on that scope will also change which will also destroy my hierarchy object. Any guidance on how to create this directive? Any help would be appreciated. I created a fiddle to play with.

[CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vgdagpin/e478n2pc/2/)

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what kind of help you are asking for i.e. help with fixing a bug in your code or ideas for a possible algorithm....?

Directives are not meant to manipulate your model/scope, they are used to manipulate the DOM, so what you want to do is build out your feature in your controller and then create a directive that is capable of recursively traversing the model and rendering it to the DOM.

See this fiddle to get you started
http://jsfiddle.net/ObiOne86/e478n2pc/4/

**UPDATE**

I think what you want to achieve might be achievable with a simple template rather than having to worry about the nuances of a using directives. Please see this new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ObiOne86/vef7toLt/4/) for a working example that meets your objectives

```
     var app = angular.module('TempExplorer', []);
app.controller("TempExplorerCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

    $scope.Directory = [new Directory('My Documents')];
    $scope.CurrentPath = {};
    $scope.selectPath = function (path) {
        $scope.CurrentPath = path;
    }
}]);

function Directory(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = name;
    self.CreatedOn = new Date();
    self.Directories = [];

    self.AddChild = function (childName) {
        self.Directories.push(new Directory(childName));
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div ng-app="TempExplorer">
    <script id="tempTemplate.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <div> Dir: {{dir.Name}} <br /> <button ng-click="dir.AddChild('A Child')"> Add Child </button>
        <button ng-click="selectPath(dir)">Select Me</button></div> 
        <div class="subdir" ng-repeat="dir in dir.Directories" ng-include="'tempTemplate.html'"></div>
    </script>
    <div ng-controller="TempExplorerCtrl">Rename:
        <input ng-model="CurrentPath.Name" />
        <div ng-repeat="dir in Directory" ng-include="'tempTemplate.html'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Some CSS sugar**

```
.subdir {
    margin-left : 30px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.. My problem is how can i navigate to the **child node** then bind the child node to the current directive so i can change the property of that child node

Comment: I manage to do that by setting scope.ngVarTemp = the child node i selected.. BUT the value of scope.ngVarTemp which is the whole hierarchy will be gone and replaced with the child only

Comment: Question is how can i set the current node to manipulate to the directive without losing the the whole hierarchy.. just like a pointer, pointing to the current directory then manipulate then move the pointer to another directory the manipulate then navigate again to another.. Finally, i'll extract the JSON format of that whole hierarchy

Comment: No worries, I'll tweak the fiddle to see if I can get what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Hi Obi, thanks for the effort.. I made it by changing the content of ng-model to the current node and use $compile again.. Thanks by the way

Comment: No worries @VincentDagpin, just a few pointers, if you have to reference html tags using a jquery selector in your directive, that's usually a sign of bad design in angularjs. It's good that you have solved this problem but the solution may not suffice for other problems you might encounter in the future plus since your directive is dependent on your UI, it becomes completely unreusable. It should make a decent learning exercise for you to try to rewrite your directive to be independent of your UI. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Updated code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e478n2pc/3/). It may be provide your requirements. May be not.

I removed `$scope.CurrentPath.Directories = [];`  this line if you need this line you can add in its block. Otherwise click event pushes without removing.